# how to extract outline of pdfs from pdf bundle file and write it to csv file using bash script or node.js

Tags: node.js, bash, pdf, pdftk, pdf-extraction

I have a  pdf bundle,i need to extract outline name  of   each  pdf and   write  it to   csv  file using   bash  script or  node.js.I am  using  pdftk  library in bash script.In bash script i have use   this command 
pdftk input.pdf burst output output_%02d.pdf   but    actually i want  outline  name of page instead of output_%02d.pdf  if this is possible then i can extract outline name from each     file name of  individual pdf 
[image]

Comment: `pdftk input.pdf dump_data` will produce outline information in the form of
`BookmarkBegin`, `BookmarkTitle`, `BookmarkLevel` and `BookmarkPageNumber`.
As you know some pdf pages may have multiple bookmarks and some page may have
none. You need to consider how to assign individual page to an appropriate
bookmark title as a filename.

Comment: Hi   how will    rearrange this pdftk input.pdf burst output output_%02d.pdf     this command   getting   generated  pdf file name as  outline name

Comment: or how it to write  all outline name to a csv file?

Comment: I have used  this command then   sample.txt   file   like as  BookmarkTitle: ASI-530000,BookmarkTitle: Page 1,BookmarkTitle: RAB904_S        but i want to write   BookmarkTitle: ASI-530000  then how will  identify   this item only

Comment: Is it possible to point me to an example of pdf file? Then we can discuss based on an actual sample. BR.